# JavaFX2 wrapping launch4j as maven plugin

Tags: java, javafx-2

Hello I am trying to wrap an javaFX-jar with launch4j maven plugin.

But the execution fails:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/applicatio
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

It looks like the exe cannot find the jfxruntime.
If I start the program with "java -jar ..." it works fine.

Here is partial of my pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding></encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.myprogram.Main</mainClass>
                <bundleType>ALL</bundleType>
                <vendor>me</vendor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.bluestemsoftware.open.maven.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>l4j-gui</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <outfile>target/MyProgram.exe/outfile>
                        <jar>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-jfx.jar</jar>
                        <errTitle>App Err</errTitle>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>org.myprogram.Main</mainClass>
                        </classPath>                            
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>                              
                            <initialHeapSize>128</initialHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                        </jre>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the version of the JRE you are specifying. JavaFX (version 2.2) wasn't bundled with the JRE until 1.7 update 6. I think your minVersion setting is probably accepting a JRE that is update 5 or earlier and the JavaFX libraries aren't installed (correctly). Try specifying `<minVersion>1.7.0_09</minVersion>` and see if that works.

I seem to remember that if you have a 64bit update 6 and a 32bit update 5 launcher4j will pick the 32bit version even though the 64bit would be better. That might explain why it works in your development environment but not when built.

Other than that your POM configuration looks pretty much the same as mine which works fine.

**Edit**

This works for me...

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
<artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.5.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>l4j-gui</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>launch4j</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
            <headerType>gui</headerType>
            <jar>mapp.jar</jar>
            <outfile>${project.build.directory}/dist/myapp.exe</outfile>
            <errTitle/>
            <cmdLine/>
            <chdir/>
            <priority>normal</priority>
            <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
            <supportUrl/>
            <customProcName>false</customProcName>
            <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
            <manifest/>
            <icon/>
            <jre>
                <path/>
                <minVersion>1.7.0_09</minVersion>
                <maxVersion/>
                <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                <initialHeapSize>256</initialHeapSize>
                <maxHeapSize>3000</maxHeapSize>
            </jre>
            <splash>
                <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/build/splash.bmp</file>
                <waitForWindow>true</waitForWindow>
                <timeout>60</timeout>
                <timeoutErr>true</timeoutErr>
            </splash>
            <versionInfo>
                <fileVersion>0.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                <fileDescription>Desc</fileDescription>
                <copyright>Company 2013</copyright>
                <productVersion>0.0.0.0</productVersion>
                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                <productName>My App</productName>
                <companyName>Company</companyName>
                <internalName>myapp</internalName>
                <originalFilename>myapp.exe</originalFilename>
            </versionInfo>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: I have specified the min version with 1.7.0_17 an deinstalled all other java version.
Still the same problem have you used launch4j for a jfx2 project?

Comment: One of our products uses JavaFX 2 and an exe is built with launch4j. I use a different build of the plugin to you but the configuration is the same (see answer edit). I seem to remember I got most of my settings from this page: http://9stmaryrd.com/tools/launch4j-maven-plugin/

Comment: Thank you very much, I used your config and it worked well. 
I Think the problem is the other wrapper.

Comment: Futher investigation showed, that the sampe problem occours when I add an explicit classpath.